# Why does my virtualenv python3 work fine on my local machine but not when I upload the virtualenv to the server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

If I install a virtualenv on my local machine, activate it and try to run python3 then it works fine (with the imported modules). However, after I send it to the live server (using scp and filezilla) it gives the error:

```
-bash: /<path>/venv4/bin/python3: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

This also happens with python and python3.8 in the same package.

I have tried reinstalling virtualenv and pipx, recreating the virtualenv and reuploading a few times.

It seems that it can't find the module, as when I activate the virtualenv on the live server and type "which python3" then it shows me the system python3:

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

It also does not work if I try to execute the venv's python3 directly, using the full path.

The reason I'm doing this is because the old virtualenv I was using has stopped working because it can't seem to find the installed modules anymore. I'm not sure why.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This can only work if the server and your desktop are the same OS with same library versions. `Exec format error` means it was compiled for a different OS or architecture.

Comment: both are 64 bit... anything else I should check for?

Comment: Are they both 64bit of the same OS with the same version of python, glibc, etc?

Comment: no im running mac and the server is linux, it wasnt a problem before though

Comment: Then it's not the same OS and architecture.

Comment: In general, don't try to copy virtualenvs around. Use them in development to isolate your environments and define your dependencies in a `requirements.txt` (for `pip`), `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` (for `pipenv`) or `pyproject.toml` and `poetry.lock` (for `poetry`). Use those _files_ to build similar environments in production.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try that out

Answer (score 1):

I believe some pip packages contain more than just python code, and must be compiled.  If your host OS is different from your server OS, or you have different libraries installed, the host-compiled code will not be compatible with your server.

Common practice is to create a file with a list of required packages, using something like

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

and rebuild the environment on the server, using something like

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is I can't execute pip from the virtualenv either. I cant install venv directly on the server because it's not allowed by the hosting provider. EDIT: will try from Pipfile

Comment: What about python?  Does your server have the right version of python installed?

Comment: yep it has python3

Comment: Then it looks like you have two options: 1. Install pip/virtualenv manually in a different location than the place you are not allowed to install them and use as a python module, `python -m pip install ...`, `python -m virtualenv venv`.  You will likely have to somehow specify the place you installed them in the commands as well, I’m just not sure what the flags are for that. 2. Set up a virtual machine with the same OS and libraries as the server, build the venv in there, and deploy that to the server.